# is it possible to get distinct results when using an NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a product search that searches the ProductCategories my products are in, sometimes my products are in multiple categories which gives me duplicate results.  I don't want to search the product table directly because there are several products that have multiple sizes but are basically the same product.

Is there a way to get distinct search results with an NSFetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can...

look out for the method

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController;
```

and add there the following lines (in this example we get only the distinct "title" attribute of our managed objects):

```
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"title"]];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
```

you have to take care how you access the values from the NSFetchedResultsController... For example in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

use the following code to access the data:

```
NSDictionary* title = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [title objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the solution which Shingoo provided, please don't forget to **set** the *NSFetchedResultsController's* **delegate to nil** in order to disable automatic updates, which won't work with *NSDictionaryResultType* and distinct values:

```
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a NSPredicate (See [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/))

It's complex, but you can do it using a SUBQUERY

Comment: ferdil – Can you elaborate your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

When creating your `NSFetchRequest` you can use `-setReturnsDistinctResults:` and set it to `YES`.

Comment: to use that you have to also set setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType which an NSFetchedResultsController does not like

Comment: @Slee: To be more precise: FRC does not support NSDictionaryResultType.